# Simple probabilty question got me stumped

Tags: probability

So here is the problem:
Six containers contain twenty four balls equally divided among each container (4 in each container). The color of the balls in each container is same and unique to that container. If we select two balls at random (without replacement) then what is the probability that they are of the same color.

So my reasoning is thus:

Total number of balls = 6*4 = 24. Total number of ways to select 2 balls is 24*23(denominator)

Number of ways to pick 2 balls from one container: 4*3 (similar balls). We can do this six times as there are six different containers. So total number of ways to pick two balls of same color = 4*3*6

Probability of picking same color is 4*3*6/(24*23) = 3/23

Am I on the right track?

Clarifications:
Each of the six containers has exactly 4 balls each. Each container has balls of a different color, so total of 24 balls with 6 different colors. I mean, container A has four balls of green, container B has four balls of yellow etc. In terms of selection, the question from what I recollect was "2 balls are chosen at random"

Comment: Are all the balls in a given container the same color? And each container has a unique color for the balls in it?

Comment: Questions: You say the six containers contain four similar balls. Is that each? (You seems to imply it is four similar balls each later, but do not explicitly state this). Are they similar because they are the same color? (Again, this is not explicitly stated, but definitely implied). You say the color of the balls in each container is different, but you do not specify from different from what? From the other balls in the container? Or do you mean all balls in a single container are the same color, and the color of balls in one container is different from the color of balls in any other?

Comment: More questions: What is meant by "select two balls at random"? Does that mean choose a random ball from among the 24 balls, then choose a random ball from among the remaining 23 balls? Or does it mean choose a random container and grab a random ball in that container, then choose a random container a second time and take a second ball at random?

Comment: @MPW: Yes you are correct

Comment: @InterstellarProbe clarified the language a bit. Thanks

Comment: @ChandanNayak With those clarifications, I can see two answers. Your answer appears valid. The other answer that seems appropriate would be: Choose one container at random, choose any of the balls from the bin, then choose a container at random a second time, and choose any of the balls from that bin. This gives you two balls chosen at random, but the probability they are the same color is $$\dfrac{1}{6}$$ since you have a one in six chance of choosing the same container twice in a row.

Comment: @ChandanNayak It is actually fairly important in probability theory to have a well-defined sampling methodology. Because the methodology is ambiguous, it leads to multiple possible answers. In practice, adequate description of the sampling methodology is extremely important, and academic papers have been rejected due to such ambiguities.

Comment: how might he select 'any ball' on the second pick, with no bias between individual balls?  I think you can see that a complex arrangement would need to be in place for that to happen, as opposed to rolling a die to pick an urn each time.  There would need to be weighted odds on picking urns that had already been chosen

Comment: @Cato sorry just the best I could recollect from a test. I think your answer makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to the subject picking one of 6 urns at random each time.  That seems the most logical to me, there does not seem to be any likely process by which he will independently pick any of the 23 remaining balls on choice 2 with equal probability.

Therefore I think the chances that he picks any colour on choice 1 is 1.
On choice 2 the chances that he picks the same urn, and therefore the same colour is 1/6, hence the probability of two balls the same colour is 1/6

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. To specify the number of ways of selecting balls of the same color, you need to specify the number of ways of selecting a color, and the no. of ways of choosing two balls of **that** color.